# Randomzie elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to randomize my deck of cards. I want to do this in the bottom function, only I am getting a multi-char array> I am trying to check if destination element is empty, if it is it will place the top card from the unshuffled deck into the array and so on and so forth by constantly checking to see if destination[randomNumber] is null. How can I do this? Am I going about this correctly?

```
// deck of cards
// below are initializations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//globals
const int maxCards = 52;

//Structs
struct card {
char suit[8];
char rank[6];
int cvalue;
char location;
};

//Function List
char * strcopy(char destination[], const char source[]);
void shuffle(card destination[],card source[]);

//program
int main()
{

//begin seeding the time
srand(time(NULL));

//constants
bool gameOn =true;
int choice;
char tempSuit[8];
char tempRank[maxCards];

//create struct array
card deck[52]; 

//Shuffle function
void shuffle(card destination[],card source[])
{

int randomNumber;
for(int i=0;i<52;i++)
{
randomNumber = rand()%52;

while(destination[i].cvalue != '/0')
{
randomNumber = rand()%52;
{
destination[randomNumber].suit = source[i].suit;
destination[randomNumber].rank = source[i].rank;
destination[randomNumber].cvalue = source[i].cvalue;
}


}
```

Comment: I recommend indenting your code to make it easier for people to read.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::random_shuffle` (C++03) or `std::shuffle` (C++11):

```
card deck[52];
// init cards ...

std::random_shuffle(deck, deck + 52);
```

or

```
card deck[52];
// init cards ...

unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

std::shuffle(std::begin(deck), std::end(deck), std::default_random_engine(seed));
```